# I need begin a project with react-tabulator

Tags: reactjs, tabulator

With react-tabulator I can use the same options that has Tabulator (javascript)?
I need begin a project with react and not sure how to use react-tabulator

Comment: Take a look at the official repository of `react-tabulator` and its examples. https://github.com/ngduc/react-tabulator

Comment: I not see its docs

Comment: you can clone this example for your project:
https://codesandbox.io/s/0mwpy612xw?module=/src/components/Home.js

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should be able to use any of the Tabulator options in react-tabulator.  If you find any specific issues, you would be best off creating an issue on the [github project](https://github.com/ngduc/react-tabulator/issues).

Here is a [link](https://github.com/ngduc/react-tabulator/blob/master/src/ReactTabulatorExample.tsx) to the example in the documentation.

Here is a simplified example.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import ReactTabulator from 'react-tabulator'

const columns = [
  { title: 'Name', field: 'name'}
];
const data = [
  { name: 'Oli Bob'},
  { name: 'Mary May' }
];

const TabulatorComponent = <ReactTabulator columns={columns} data={data} />;
```